# Justifying Vector Calculus Identities: $(u \times \nabla) \times v$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

The following relates to a conversation I had in the [comments of an earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3613321/81360).

When considering an expression like $(u \times \nabla) \times v$, it is supposedly possible to apply the [vector triple product identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product) in an unjustified (though "formally correct") way to get a correct simplification such as $(u\times \nabla) \times v = \nabla(u\cdot v) - (v\cdot \nabla) u$.  In particular, the vector triple product formula states that for vectors $a,b,c \in \Bbb R^3$, we have
$$
(a \times b) \times c = (a \cdot c)b - (b \cdot c)a = b(a \cdot c) - (c \cdot b)a.
$$
If we treat $\nabla$ as a vector, then "plugging in" to the above yields $(u\times \nabla) \times v = \nabla(u\cdot v) - (v\cdot \nabla) u$.

Is there a rigorous approach to simplifying $(u \times \nabla) \times v$ (and other such expressions) that makes use of vector identities in a similar fashion?

---

Edit: Having derived a correct simplification in my answer below, it seems that the supposed identity I give above is incorrect (or at least, it seems to be since I don't see how the two expressions would be equal; I have not gone through the trouble of finding a $u,v$ that disprove the identity, though).

In some sense, the solution $(u \times \nabla) \times v = u \cdot (\nabla v) - u(\nabla \cdot v)$ fits the form of $(a \times b) \times c = (a \cdot c)b - a(b \cdot c)$, though it is perhaps counterintuitive that the first term should be $u \cdot (\nabla v)$ which, if the triple product rule can be directly applied in this context, should be our interpretation of $(u \cdot v)\nabla$.

Interestingly, we find that
$$
u \times (\nabla \times v) = u \cdot (\nabla v) - (u \cdot \nabla)v
$$
The associated vector identity is $a \times (b \times c) = (a \cdot c)b - (a \cdot b) c$.  Again, the second term seems to "behave as expected".

Comment: I have some sort of answer that I intend to post below, but I would be interested in seeing any other approaches

Comment: If anybody cares to post a proof/simplification using the usual approach via Einstein summation notation and Levi Cevita symbols, I would be interested in seeing that written out and seeing how it compares to my approach.

Comment: Answers using the Levi-Cevita symbols can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170937/expand-veca-times-nabla-times-vecb-using-tensorial-notation?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942082/prove-frac12-mathbf-nabla-u-cdot-u-u-times-nabla-times-u-u?rq=1).

Comment: @mattos Good find, thanks for that

Comment: Also, a simpler answer than in the above links \begin{align} [(u \times \nabla) \times v]_{i} &= \epsilon_{ijk} (u \times \nabla)_{j} v_{k} \\ &= \epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{jlm} u_{l} \partial_{m} v_{k} \\ &= \epsilon_{jki} \epsilon_{jlm} u_{l} \partial_{m} v_{k} \\ &= (\delta_{kl} \delta_{im} - \delta_{km} \delta_{il}) u_{l} \partial_{m} v_{k} \\ &= u_{k} \partial_{i} v_{k} - u_{i} \partial_{k} v_{k} \end{align} which agrees with the direct computation of $(u \times \nabla) \times v = u \cdot (\nabla v) - u (\nabla \cdot v)$.

Comment: @mattos That's a gorgeous answer, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $f: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$, $u,v:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$, write $v = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and take $e_1,e_2,e_3$ to be the canonical basis vectors (that is, $i,j,k$). We can write $v = \sum_{j=1}^3 v_j e_j$, and
$$
\nabla \cdot v = \sum_{i=1}^3 e_i \cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i},
\qquad \nabla \times v = \sum_{i=1}^3 e_i \times \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i},
\\
(v \cdot \nabla)f = \sum_{i=1}^3 (v \cdot e_i) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}, \qquad 
(v \times \nabla)f = \sum_{i=1}^3 (v \times e_i) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i},\\
(u \times \nabla) \times v = \sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 [(u \times e_i) \times e_j] \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}.
$$
With that stated, we can now apply the triple vector product identity to get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 [(u \times e_i) \times e_j] \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i} &= 
\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 [(u \cdot e_j)e_i - (e_i \cdot e_j)u] \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}
\\ &=
\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 u_j\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i} e_i
- 
\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 \delta_{ij} u\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i} \\ &= 
\sum_{j=1}^3 u_j \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i} e_i
- 
u\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_i} \\ & = 
\sum_{j=1}^3 u_j \nabla v
- 
u\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_i} = 
u \cdot (\nabla v) - u(\nabla \cdot v).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @mattos I'll be happy to clean things up once I'm finished writing them.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realise you were still going. One final note, I'm pretty sure you could use summation notation to prove the statement.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "summation notation". Perhaps you mean using Einstein summation notation and [Levi-Cevita symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol).  If that's what you mean, then that's definitely a reasonable approach; I guess I'm avoiding it because I find the [product simplification rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Product) to be unintuitive.

Comment: Why is it just a partial answer? The product simplification rule might be unintuitive, but it makes the calculation easier and it's quite easy to remember (I do it this way: $\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{ipq}=\delta\delta-\delta\delta$, and the indices of the first batch of deltas are in order, i.e. $j$ with $p$ and $k$ with $q$, and mixed up for the second portion, i.e. $j$ with $q$ and $k$ with $p$. The order of these does not matter, because the identity matrix is symmetric and the product of real numbers is commutative)

Comment: @Botond It was a partial answer while I was still editing it, and I forgot to remove that at the beginning. That's an interesting mnemonic, but my objection stands

Comment: Why do you find it unintuitive?

Comment: @Botond "Why do you find X unintuitive" is a difficult question to answer.  [One answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11267/81360) I can give you is that I find it unintuitive because I haven't used it very often and so I'm not accustomed to it.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, the theory of geometric algebra can give you this calculation (and many others) as a one-liner.

$$ u\times (\nabla \times v) = i\left(u\wedge i(\nabla \wedge v)\right) = - u\cdot (\nabla \wedge v) = u\cdot(\nabla v) - (u\cdot\nabla)v, $$
where $\wedge$ denotes the exterior product, $i = e_1\wedge e_2\wedge e_3$ denotes the unit pseudoscalar of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and we used that $a\times b = i(a\wedge b)=a\cdot(ib)$ along with the "cab-bac" identity.

Comment: That's an interesting perspective, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170937/expand-veca-times-nabla-times-vecb-using-tensorial-notation?rq=1) you seem to miss a term $\boldsymbol{u}\times(\nabla\times\boldsymbol{v})$ on RHS. The deduction is exactly the same.

I mean, the equality should be
$$(\boldsymbol{u}\times\nabla)\times\boldsymbol{v}=\boldsymbol{u}\times(\nabla\times\boldsymbol{v})+\boldsymbol{u}\cdot\nabla\boldsymbol{v}-\boldsymbol{u}(\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{v})$$