# Are there some vector calculus identities that you can't prove using differential forms?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, differential-forms

There are some vector calculus identites involving operators like $(v \times \nabla)$ , $ (v \cdot \nabla)$ etc ([concrete example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3904518/proving-a-vector-calculus-identity?noredirect=1&lq=1)). To my knowledge, there is no similar equivalent such in Forms, does this mean some vector calculus identities can't be shown in the frame work of forms? or, can forms be modified to accommodate such operations?

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Didn't I link a post @deane

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see that. I haven't looked at that identity carefully. I suspect that although it can be formulated and proved using differential forms, it probably isn't worth the trouble.